# How do you remove the required SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission for release version of a React Native Android app?

Tags: react-native, android-manifest, android-permissions

From what [I've read](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886), React Native requires the permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` to enable its developer interface in debug mode. However, when publishing a release, this permission is still included, which causes users to freak out (since it says "permission to draw over other apps").

I can manually remove the permission in AndroidManifest.xml, but that will break the app when I'm in development mode -- and that's not something I want to do every time I release a new version.

Is there a way to disable the permission for only release versions of the app?

Comment: Issue is filed and discussed here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5886

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution for Android Studio, I hope react-native have the same functions:

You can have two separate `AndroidManifest.xml` for release and debug versions.

Debug manifest should be located in `${projectPath}\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`
Release manifest in `${projectPath}\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

You can put `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` only in debug manifest and don't add this into release.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> android ->app ->src

create a folder named release and add a AndroidManifest file with the following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flexycabsdrivers"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

</manifest>
```

On build the release AndroidManifest should remove the permission, you can add other permissions you want to remove.